# Why do ZIP files change size?

Tags: backup, zip, size

I am backing up one external hard drive to another, where the second drive has a previously created backup of the data (2019-09-22).  One sub-sub-sub directory contains four ZIP files, where original filenames are not shown for privacy:

- File A, last modified 2009-05-04 19:41:46; 9451350 bytes in 2019 backup and 9448202 bytes in "current" drive
- File B, last modified 2009-05-05 12:00:20; 76439 bytes in both
- File C, last modified 2009-05-04 18:35:44; 9659304 bytes in 2019 backup and 9656160 bytes in "current" drive
- File D, last modified 2009-05-04 18:20:46; 9367216 bytes in 2019 backup and 9364068 bytes in "current" drive

I have not touched these files or done any work related to the subject matter of this content in more than two years.  Why would the file size have changed for these ZIP directories, especially without any accompanying change in the date modified?

I also noticed an additional ZIP file in another directory on the backup had been deleted from the "current" drive, but this may have been due to an overzealous virus-risk checker.

All 5 of the ZIP files referenced in this question likely contain at least some source code and documentation for old projects.  The missing ZIP file was an open-source repository for a web application; file B appears to be C code, and files A, C, and D likely include at least some Verilog (hardware description language) and code to interface with the described hardware.  I personally wrote the code in A-D but likely incorporated some standard libraries with it.

---

Update in response to comments:
While [cluster sizes do differ](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-do-i-determine-my-hard-disks-cluster-size/680958f6-b946-4ccb-aed4-dbd56bdd480e) between the disks, going directly to each file properties I can see Size different, not just size on disk. Last mod dates are the same for both files but creation dates do differ (Feb 16 2016 on the backup and Dec 30 2018 on the main drive), and are both several years after the last modified date. Winmerge shows three HTML files as removed from each ZIP; Winmerge shows them as empty and they don't appear on an Extract All.  Upon further investigation, on unzipping Windows Defender immediately removes these three files claiming detection of "[Exploit:HTML/IframeRef.gen](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=Exploit%3AHTML%2FIframeRef.gen&threatid=2147536539)."  Upon removing one set of the three HTML files from quarantine and inspecting them with a text editor, I see lines containing iframe tags (with close tags) with attributes like the following, once in one of the HTML files and 17 times in sequence in each of the other two, all identical, all just before the close body tag.

> src="http:/ /jL.c& #104;uxx.pl/rc/" style="& #100;isplay:none"

I have changed two letters in the second-level domain of the src URL (to xx) and added a space between the slashes, as well as a space between the ampersand and hash symbols in both instances, as it does seem suspicious.

These HTML files appear to have been autogenerated with an HTML page title of "Xilinx Design Summary" citing product version "ISE, 8.1.03i". They appear to have been outputs accompanying automatic conversion from Verilog hardware description files to binary instructions for programming an [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array).

I agree with Windows Defender that this looks quite suspicious, but I don't know how those lines got in there, or when & why those files get silently removed from ZIP archives without changing the last modified date.  I also don't know why these would be different considering the backup was 2019 and the creation dates on the files are from 2016 and 2018 respectively.

Any insights, other than "don't open that in a browser?" Is this something I should be more seriously concerned about?  Should I unzip from backup, restore from quarantine, remove the iframe lines in a text editor, and rezip to preserve the rest of the data?

I'm pretty sure that the original computer used to generate the file is no longer in service, and my current main machine was purchased a couple months after the date of the 2019 backup.  I might also note that I don't think I've substantively used or touched these files since the May 2009 last modified dates, other than this specific exploration.

Comment: Different cluster size?

Comment: The file size (content length) would most certainly not change. Are you perhaps looking at the size on disk?

Comment: Use a tool such as WinMerge (which can handle Zip archives) or KDiff to compare the files. If need be, extract them to separate folders and diff the folders.

Comment: Comments responded to in significant edit, below the horizontal line!